# Using the .reduce function to made certain calculations and return an object with array results

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reduce

So I've successfully managed to get the results I'm after:

```js
const days = [
{
    date: '2016-12-13T00:00:00.000Z',
    stats: [
      { name: 'Soft Drinks', sold: 34, },
      { name: 'Snacks', sold: 3, },
      { name: 'Coffee and warm drinks', sold: 26, },
    ],
  },
  {
    date: '2016-12-14T00:00:00.000Z',
    stats: [
      { name: 'Soft Drinks', sold: 34, },
      
      { name: 'Snacks', sold: 3, },
      { name: 'Coffee and warm drinks', sold: 26, },
    ],
  },
];

const newStats = days.reduce(function (pastDay, currentDay) {
  const nextStats = currentDay.stats.map(function(stat) {
   const oldSold = pastDay.stats.find(function (old) {
     return old.name === stat.name;
    });
    
   const newSold = stat.sold + oldSold.sold;
   stat.sold = newSold;
    return stat;
  });

  return {
    stats: nextStats,
  };
});

console.log(newStats);
```

Outputs:

```
{
  "stats": [
    {
      "name": "Soft Drinks",
      "sold": 68
    },
    {
      "name": "Snacks",
      "sold": 6
    },
    {
      "name": "Coffee and warm drinks",
      "sold": 52
    }
  ]
}
```

Which is exactly what I'm after, however when dealing with a different days array, that follow the same structure of array of objects. I'm getting an undefined error on `pastDay` anyone can help me spot the problem? or help me find alternative to `.reduce`

The array I'm having trouble with:

```js
const days = [  
   {  
      "_id":{  
         "_str":"f23f02994ab992437e423e24"
      },
      "date":"2016-12-13T00:00:00.000Z",
      "statistics":{  
         "breakdown":{  
            "byTurnover":[  
               {  
                  "name":"Soft Drinks",
                  "sold":34,
                  "percentage":31.14
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Snacks",
                  "sold":3,
                  "percentage":2.65
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Coffee and warm drinks",
                  "sold":26,
                  "percentage":21.54
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Brandy",
                  "sold":2,
                  "percentage":2.75
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Beer",
                  "sold":20,
                  "percentage":20.15
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Mixed drinks Other",
                  "sold":21,
                  "percentage":21.77
               }
            ],
         }
      },
      "id":{  
         "_str":"f23f02994ab992437e423e24"
      }
   },
   {  
      "_id":{  
         "_str":"b3d0ad7f314e33021739f70c"
      },
      "date":"2016-12-14T00:00:00.000Z",
      "statistics":{  
         "breakdown":{  
            "byTurnover":[  
               {  
                  "name":"Soft Drinks",
                  "sold":34,
                  "percentage":31.14
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Snacks",
                  "sold":3,
                  "percentage":2.65
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Coffee and warm drinks",
                  "sold":26,
                  "percentage":21.54
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Brandy",
                  "sold":2,
                  "percentage":2.75
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Beer",
                  "sold":20,
                  "percentage":20.15
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Mixed drinks Other",
                  "sold":21,
                  "percentage":21.77
               }
            ],
         }
      },
      "id":{  
         "_str":"b3d0ad7f314e33021739f70c"
      }
   },
   {  
      "_id":{  
         "_str":"e1906ce07ab811c74528e3cc"
      },
      "date":"2016-12-15T00:00:00.000Z",
      "statistics":{  
         "breakdown":{  
            "byTurnover":[  
               {  
                  "name":"Soft Drinks",
                  "sold":34,
                  "percentage":31.14
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Snacks",
                  "sold":3,
                  "percentage":2.65
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Coffee and warm drinks",
                  "sold":26,
                  "percentage":21.54
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Brandy",
                  "sold":2,
                  "percentage":2.75
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Beer",
                  "sold":20,
                  "percentage":20.15
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Mixed drinks Other",
                  "sold":21,
                  "percentage":21.77
               }
            ],
         }
      },
      "id":{  
         "_str":"e1906ce07ab811c74528e3cc"
      }
   },
];

const newStats = days.reduce(function (pastDay, currentDay) {
  const nextStats = currentDay.statistics.breakdown.byTurnover.map(function(stat) {
   const oldSold = pastDay.statistics.breakdown.byTurnover.find(function (old) {
     return old.name === stat.name;
    });
    
   const newSold = stat.sold + oldSold.sold;
   stat.sold = newSold;
    return stat;
  });

  return {
    stats: nextStats,
  };
});

console.log(newStats);
```

Outputs: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'breakdown' of undefined`

The .reduce code for the second array:

```
const newStats = days.reduce(function (pastDay, currentDay) {
  const nextStats = currentDay.statistics.breakdown.byTurnover.map(function(stat) {
    const oldSold = pastDay.statistics.breakdown.byTurnover.find(function (old) {
        return old.name === stat.name;
    });

    const newSold = stat.sold + oldSold.sold;
    stat.sold = newSold;
    return stat;
  });

  return {
    stats: nextStats,
  };
});

console.log(newStats);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your **first** reducer is returning an object format that matches the input array, as in

```
return {
    stats: nextStats,
};
```

And your array looks like:

```
const days = [{ stats: [...] }]
```

So when your inner loop iterates over `.stats` as an array, it will correctly run.

Your **second** reducer is iterating over an object with this structure:

```
const days = [{ statistics: { breakdown: { byTurnover: [...] } }]
```

But then returns an object not matching that structure:

```
return {
    stats: nextStats,
};
```

So the first iteration of the reducer will work, then the second iteration will run, and the first argument, `pastDay`, will be the return value of the previous run, which won't have any of the keys you're looking up.

A quick and dirty solution is just to match the object key depth when returning:

```
const newStats = days.reduce(function (pastDay, currentDay) {
    const nextStats = currentDay.statistics.breakdown.byTurnover.map(function(stat) {
        const oldSold = pastDay.statistics.breakdown.byTurnover.find(function (old) {
            return old.name === stat.name;
        });

        const newSold = stat.sold + oldSold.sold;
        stat.sold = newSold;
        return stat;
    });

    return {
        statistics: { breakdown: { byTurnover: nextStats } },
    };
});
```

While this answers the question, the logic you're using is hard to follow. Depending on what you're trying to accomplish, which is unclear from the code, this may not be an ideal way to do it.

Comment: Andy thank you so much for helping out! while this works, do you recommend different approach ?

Comment: Maybe, depending on what you want the code to do in the end

Comment: Is there a way I can return the results as in const days = [{ stats: [...] }]
 instead of the nested one?

Comment: You could massage the data first https://gist.github.com/AndrewRayCode/d9b611c2f7b8ce770c3cf43937e72115